# Installing subclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, windows-7, subclipse

Im trying to install subclipse on a windows 7 x64 machine. I allways get the error,

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Unable to read repository at http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x/plugins/org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.ui_1.6.18.jar.
Read timed out

Im installing from 
Susclipse - http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x

Anyone?

Comment: Have u tried to download http://subclipse.tigris.org/files/documents/906/49028/site-1.6.18.zip and then install from local site in Eclipse ?

Comment: Didnt know that was posible. Worked like a charm. Thanks

Comment: I guess I should post this as an answer then...

Comment: What happened to http://subclipse.tigris.org ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should download http://subclipse.tigris.org/files/documents/906/49028/site-1.6.18.zip and then install from local site in Eclipse

Comment: What happened to subclipse.tigris.org ?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, but I just tried to install again and it worked. Probably the server was out during the moment you tried.

Try downloading the new version: http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.8.x

Comment: This seems to happen frequently with subclipse site. Experienced that some times already.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue today and the reason why I had this issue is some one who had used my laptop earlier had already installed this, ensure that it is already not installed in your eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

I found Subclipse now on github https://github.com/subclipse/subclipse and they provide installation steps on the wiki page https://github.com/subclipse/subclipse/wiki

TLDR: Use https://subclipse.github.io/updates/subclipse/4.3.x/ when installing from eclipse